# PHP While Loop - Writing to Variable Multiple Times With Heredoc

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, increment, heredoc

I am writing a script to pull from the database and dynamically create a table of items. The loop I am using breaks everytime I try to increment a varible.

Here is an example with the same result:

This loop will work fine for creating multiple tables.

```
<?php

$item=array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7");
$i=0;


while($i!=count($item)){
$galleryItem.=<<<HTML
<table>
<tr>
<td>$item[$i]</td>
</tr>
</table>
HTML;
$i++;
}

echo $galleryItem;
?>
```

This loop, however, will not work. I desire for it to create two columns in the table with the complete output of the array in multiple rows.

```
<?php

$item=array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7");
$i=0;

while($i!=count($item)){

$galleryItem.=<<<HTML
<table>
<tr>
<td>$item[$i]</td>


HTML;

$i++;

$galleryItem.=<<<HTML


<td>$item[$i]</td>
</tr>
</table>
$i++;
}

echo $galleryItem;
?>
```

What might I be doing wrong? Will PHP not allow you to write to the same variable more than once in a while loop?

Comment: You don't close the last HEREDOC

Comment: Thank you, but still the code does not function

Comment: also you can do this by foreach loop

Comment: Exacty how do you want the output to be? Please edit the question and show.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of array elements. You only have 7 items but try to echo 8 elements. You should do proper boundary checks to see if you have enough elements when using them.

To start with, replace you while loop with:

```
while( $i <= count($item) ) {
   ...
}
```

But your problem is actually caused by increasing your counter `$i++` and echoing another element without checking if one actually exists. A quick fix:

```
<td><?php echo ($i <=count($item)) ? $item[$i] : ''; ?></td>
```

**UPDATE:** I've added an example of how you could do it in regular PHP without HereDoc:

```
<?php

    $item = array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7");
    $i=0;

?><table>
<?php while( $i <= count($item) ): ?>
    <?php if (($i % 2) == 0): ?><tr><?php endif ?>
        <td><?php echo ($i < count($item)) ? $item[$i] : ''; ?></td>
    <?php if (($i % 2) == 1): ?></tr><?php endif ?>
<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didnt necessarily need the ternary operator, but changing the condition to <= instead of != did the trick. Any insight as to why?

Comment: Actually, you should use `$i < count($items)` as `$i` is used as the index into the array and is zero based but `count($items)` represents the actual number. So `$i` should always remain lower than `count($items)`. I'm not familiar with HereDoc but I've added a regular PHP example.